# how action contacted the reducer to change the state of the object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am sorry it might be a silly question but i want to know i have redux store first let me explain the data flow there
The data is getting store at a global level state which i have in my store.js which have been declare in my `productReducer.js` There i define a switch statement and there i alter the state of the product

`productReducer.js`

my code here

```
import { 
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, 
    PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
    CLEAR_ERROR
} from '../constants/productConst'

export const productReducer = (state  ={product:[]},action)=>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST:
            return{
                laoding: true,
                product:[],
            }
        case PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS:
            return{
                laoding: false,
                product:action.payload.products,
                productsCount:action.payload.productCount,
            }
        case PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL:
            return{
                laoding: false,
                error:action.payload,
            }
        case CLEAR_ERROR:
            return{
                ...state,
                error:null
            }
        default:
            return {
                ...state,
            }
    }
}
```

i have action `productAction.js`

```
import axios from 'axios'


import { 
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, 
    PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
    CLEAR_ERROR
} from '../constants/productConst'

export const getProduct = () => async (dispatch) =>{
    console.log("Been executed at the action")
    try {
        dispatch({type:PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST})
        const {data} = await axios.get("api/v1/products")
        dispatch({
            type:PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
            payload:data,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type:PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
            payload:error.response.data.message,
        })
    }
}

export const clearError =() =>async (dispatch)=>{
    dispatch({type:CLEAR_ERROR})
}
```

Let me Sum up my question when i neeed to update the state from the frontend i call the action but  there is no  way the action and the reducer connected together how the state of the product is altered in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question "how do actions contact the reducer to change the state of the object?":

The overall redux store setup enables this, especially how you registered your `productReducer`.

Let's go through the typical flow to illustrate how everything is connected:

1. Somewhere in a React component, a user-interaction (e.g. button click) or something automatic dispatches the async `getProduct()` action. This is possible because `getProduct` is either a prop of the component (Redux' `connect` API) or you're using the `useDispatch` hook.
2. The store setup knows that `PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS` is handled by your `productReducer`. We go through the switch statement and now `state.product.product` holds an array of products (careful with the naming there btw, plural vs. singular).
3. Any React component interested in `state.product.product` is now notified that the state has changed. They're getting notified because either the `connect` API (`mapStateToProps`) or `useSelector` connects the state with the mounted React component. The products can now be (re-)rendered, or clicked on, etc..

Answer (score 1):

**Action**

An action is a plain JavaScript object that has a type field. You can think of an action as an event that describes something that happened in the application.

**Reducer**

You can think of a reducer as an event listener which handles events based on the received action (event) type.

By using **dispatch()** you are dispatching the event and then comes the following in the reducer logic:

- Check to see if the reducer cares about this action

  - If so, make a copy of the state, update the copy with new values, and return it
- Otherwise, return the existing state unchanged

If you are interested about more then please have a look into official redux [documentation](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-2-concepts-data-flow), there is really everything you will need.